# How to exclude a match from changes if it has some character before matched pattern?

Tags: python, regex, android-studio

I'm trying to match all occurences with `(\"[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\")` but exclude them if they have "equal" sign before like this `([^\=]\"[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\")`. How can I do that in Android studio, Notepad++ Python Script or other tools?

```
"ZAR""""""I""""""""""EUR""""""""AED""AFN""ALL""AMD""ANG""AOA""ARS""AUD""AWG"
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="AED" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="AFN" />
```

I want to exclude android:text="AFN (or other letters)"

Comment: Provide examples. Do the items always have 3 capital letters?

Comment: Yes. They always have 3 capital letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Notepad++, based on the provided example, you can try:

- Find what:`(?<!\=)"[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"`
- Search mode: Regular expression

Use negative lookbehind `(?<!\=)` to find 3 capital letters items with quotes before and after `"[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"`, but not when there is an `=` before them.

Comment: Nice, works on Android Studio as well.